# How can I clear specific bits in a register to 0 regardless of what state they are in

Tags: c, embedded, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, firmware

I am trying to write either one of the following values to a TX register: `0x00, 0x01, 0x10, 0x11`.

The function has the write split onto two parts based on what TX_WRITE function is called. The TX pins are mapped to specific ports on the microcontroller, and I am trying to write these values into these registers without modifying the other non-TX pins. Both write functions will essentially be the same so I'll just talk about the `_TX_1_8_Write` function.

TX IO 1-8 Pins:

```
     IO1-4: P5.5 - P5.2
     IO5  : P4.7
     IO6  : P5.0
     IO7  : P4.5
     IO8: : P4.4

     i.e. bits for IO 1-8 are:
     | P4.4 | P4.5 | P5.0 | P4.7 | P5.2 | P5.3 | P5.4 | P5.5 |
```

If I wanted to set all TX bits to 0x00 and keep other bits the same, it would look something like this:

```
    P5: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1      |      P5: 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
    P4: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1      |      P4: 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
                             |
            TO              OR              TO
                             |
    P5: 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0      |      P5: 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
    P4: 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1      |      P5: 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

I have tried masking the values with `1` and bitshifting by the modified bits, but the register doesn't always update all the bits I require. Here's what I have so far:

```
#define BIT0                   (0x0001)
#define BIT1                   (0x0002)
#define BIT2                   (0x0004)
#define BIT3                   (0x0008)
#define BIT4                   (0x0010)
#define BIT5                   (0x0020)
#define BIT6                   (0x0040)
#define BIT7                   (0x0080)
#define BIT8                   (0x0100)
#define BIT9                   (0x0200)

void _MSP_TX_1_8_Write(unsigned char regVal)
{
//     IO1-4: P5.5 - P5.2
//     IO5  : P4.7
//     IO6  : P5.0
//     IO7  : P4.5
//     IO8: : P4.4

    switch(regVal)
    {
        case 0x00:
            P5OUT &= ~(1 << (BIT5 | BIT4 | BIT3 | BIT2 | BIT0));
            P4OUT &= ~(1 << (BIT7 | BIT5 | BIT4));
            break;
        case 0x01:
            P5OUT &= ~(1 << (BIT0 | ~(BIT4 | BIT3 | BIT2 | BIT1)));
            P4OUT &= ~(1 << ~(BIT7 | BIT5 | BIT4));
            break;
        case 0x10:
            P5OUT &= ~(1 << (BIT4 | ~(BIT1 | BIT3 | BIT2 | BIT0));
            P4OUT &= ~(1 << ~(BIT7 | BIT5 | BIT4));
            break;
        case 0x11:
            P5OUT &= ~(1 << (BIT0 | ~(BIT4 | BIT3 | BIT2 | BIT1)));
            P4OUT &= ~(1 << (BIT4 | ~(BIT7 | BIT5));
            break;
        default:
            _MSP_TX_1_8_Write(0x00);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can mask a bit either by an absolute hex mask like `0x80` or by a bit number and shift such as `1u << 3`. This code attempts both versions at once, which is why nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to `&` the bits I wish to modify. Port mapping on this MC is mapped to 8bit register so shifting is not required.

```c
void _MSP_TX_1_8_Write(unsigned char regVal)
{
//     IO1-4: P5.5 - P5.2
//     IO5  : P4.7
//     IO6  : P5.0
//     IO7  : P4.5
//     IO8: : P4.4

    switch(regVal)
    {
        case 0x00:
            P5OUT &= ~(BIT5 | BIT4 | BIT3 | BIT2 | BIT0);
            P4OUT &= ~(BIT7 | BIT5 | BIT4);
            break;
        case 0x01:
            P5OUT &= BIT0 | ~(BIT4 | BIT3 | BIT2 | BIT1);
            P4OUT &= ~(BIT7 | BIT5 | BIT4);
            break;
        case 0x10:
            P5OUT &= BIT4 | ~(BIT1 | BIT3 | BIT2 | BIT0);
            P4OUT &= ~(BIT7 | BIT5 | BIT4);
            break;
        case 0x11:
            P5OUT &= BIT0 | ~(BIT4 | BIT3 | BIT2 | BIT1);
            P4OUT &= BIT4 | ~(BIT7 | BIT5);
            break;
        default:
            _MSP_TX_1_8_Write(0x00);
            break;
    }
}
```